# how to import variable from a different js file?

Tags: javascript, import, export

I've been looking into the ES6 docs about import and export. It's pretty straightforward yet I can't get it to work. I'm just trying to import simple variables from a js file to be used inside a function. I'm using the variables accross several pages. I don't want to have to hardcode everytime. How do I achieve that?

**config.js**

```
var app_mode = 0;
if(app_mode ===0){
var mapboxtoken = 'pk.eytest';
}else{
var mapboxtoken = 'pk.eylive';
}
```

**map.js**

```
function mapOverview(){

mapboxgl.accessToken = mapboxtoken;//use mapboxtoken variable here

//rest of code...
      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use nodejs you may export from `module.exports`:

**config.js**

```
const app_mode = 0;
const  mapboxtoken =  (app_mode ===0) ? 'pk.eytest' : 'pk.eylive';
module.exports.mapboxtoken = mapboxtoken;
```

**map.js**

```
const {mapboxtoken} = require('./config.js');
// or
const config = require('./config.js');

function mapOverview(){
  console.log(mapboxtoken);//use mapboxtoken variable here
  //or
  console.log(config.mapboxtoken);//use mapboxtoken variable here
}
mapOverview();
```

**output:**

```
pk.eytest
pk.eytest
```

also read here: [import-export](https://javascript.info/import-export)

Comment: Can I use this without node?

Comment: In browser? In browser usually 'import'  but  what is your project?

Comment: I'm just using a mix of pure  vanilla javascript and jquery at the moment nothing fancy.

Comment: you can use global variables, like window.myVar = 'value' then you can see it everywhere

Comment: also if you have 2 js files , just add in header <script src="path" > for each in right order

Comment: Yes the files are in the right order and it doesn't work. For some reason I can't access it just by ordering them so I do have to use one of the answers suggested here.

Comment: please make https://codesandbox.io project and put your code there

Answer (score 0):

In the config file you need to add this piece of code maybe at the end:

```
export mapboxtoken;
```

In the map file import the variable as below(assuming both files are in the same directory):

```
import { mapboxtoken } from './config';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main module solutions for JavaScript today.

If you use ES6, then use `export` and `import`:

```
// A.js
export const SomeConst = 'blabla'

// B.js
import { SomeConst } from 'A.js'
console.log(SomeConst) // blabla
```

If you use Node.js, then it's commonjs, use `module.exports` and `require`:

```
// A.js
const SomeConst = 'blabla'
module.exports.SomeConst = SomeConst

// B.JS
const SomeConst = require('A.js).SomeConst
```